# Google Cloud Function Deployment Error "Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code."

Tags: c#, .net-core, deployment, google-cloud-functions

I'm creating a google cloud function using Visual Studio 2019, I've tested the code in postman and it's working normally, i am deploying using cmd with the following command:

```
gcloud functions deploy my-first-function --region=southamerica-east1 --entry-point dataVerification.FunctionVerifyData --runtime dotnet3 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated
```

But I recieve the following error:

[image]

I don't know why this error occurs, the code is working, it does not have any exceptions.

The test code I'm using is below:

```
using Google.Cloud.Functions.Framework;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Data_Verification
{
    public class VerifyData : IHttpFunction
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Logic for your function goes here.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context">The HTTP context, containing the request and the response.</param>
        /// <returns>A task representing the asynchronous operation.</returns>
        public async Task HandleAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            string body = await new StreamReader(context.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

            await context.Response.WriteAsync(body + " ");
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(context.Response.StatusCode.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have more detail in Cloud Build, or Cloud Logging?

Comment: Hi, I managed to solve the problem as I said in the post below, I don't have the logs anymore, however, I remember that it had an error when installing the .Net Core SDK packages

Answer (score -2):

Oops guys, I ended up discovering the error and it was a very simple thing. When I create a function the name that is in the function's namespace has to be the same name that I put in the folder.